# How to get a value from a field in a modal?

Tags: angular

I have a form, when I enter une value for example `test`, I would like to retrieve the value in a modal, please.

1))

[image]

2))

[image]

Here is my error message

```
error TS2339: Property 'dest' does not exist on type 'TotoResultModalComponent'.
```

Can you help me to be able to display the value in the modal please?

**PARENT**

toto.component.ts

```
export class TotoComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

  private svm: string | null = null;
  dest: string = '';


  constructor(
    private service: TotoService,
    private router: Router, 
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
    private modalService: BsModalService,
    private location: Location,

    ) { }

  
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.svm = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('svm');
      if (!this.svm) {
       
        return;
      }
   
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.unsubscribe$.next();
      this.unsubscribe$.complete();
    }


    openConfirmModal(): void {
      const modalRef = this.modalService.show(TotoResultModalComponent, {
        ...NOT_CLOSABLE_MODAL_OPTIONS,
        class: 'modal-dialog-centered modal-lg',
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-error-title',
        initialState: {

        },
  
        providers: [
        
          { provide: TotoService}
        
        ]
      });
  
    }

}
```

toto.component.html

```
<form #formulaire="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="formulaire.form.valid">
  <div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
    <div class="col text-end">
      <label for="dest" class="form-label">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <input
        id="dest"
        name="dest"
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        style="min-width: 380px"
        maxlength="25"
        [(ngModel)]="dest"
      />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col text-start">
      <button
        type="submit"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        (click)="openConfirmModal()"
        style="background-color: #239CD3;"
        [disabled]="formulaire.form.invalid"
      >
        Confirm
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**CHILD**

toto-result-modal.component.html

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped spaceLeft" style="width: 700px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 60%">Name</th>
      <td style="min-width: 100%">{{ dest}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

toto-result-modal.component.ts

```
export class TotoResultModalComponent implements OnInit {


  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();
  modalService: any;


  @Output() closeModal = new EventEmitter<void>();


  constructor(
    public modal: BsModalRef,
    private router: Router,
    private location: Location,
    private service: TotoService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.goBack();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }


  goBack(): void {
    this.modal.hide();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/transfers/toto']);   
    }); 
 
  }

 
  }
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem.
You can use [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) to create a MRE.

The good part about making a MRE is that you might end up finding the problem yourself ;)
 And in case you don't, people can use the MRE to check where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a type error because `TotoResultModalComponent` doesn't have a `dest` property, but you call it in the html. Just add the property.

for showing the outside data inside the modal, you have to get the `BsModalRef`  and set the `dest` property.

```js
openConfirmModal(): void {
      const modalRef = this.modalService.show(TotoResultModalComponent, {
        ...NOT_CLOSABLE_MODAL_OPTIONS,
        class: 'modal-dialog-centered modal-lg',
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-error-title',
        initialState: {

        },
        providers: [
          { provide: TotoService}
        ]
      });
      modalRef.content.dest = this.dest; // add this
    }
```

You can also just pass it in the initialState:

```js
initialState: {dest: this.dest}
```

This 2nd section in the modal docs has a sample.

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/modals#service-component

I don't have recent experience with valor software but it is similar to the other bootstrap component library in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service with an Observable of dest. Feed data to it in the parent component and subscribe to it in the child component. You're already providing TotoService, you could put it in there.

```js
dest$: EventEmitter<string> = new Eventemitter<string>();

dest$.emit(dest);

dest$.subscribe(_ => { ... });
```